# Commands out of sync error while calculating distance

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, distance, latitude-longitude, haversine

I am trying to calculate distance from given `Point(lat, long)` but when I use an ordering by the distance column I get `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` error.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT id, name, country_code, postal_code, latitude, longitude, 
    st_distance_sphere(
        point(50.77333, 7.185259), 
        point(latitude, longitude)
    ) AS distance 
FROM place_merged WHERE name LIKE ('ko%') ORDER BY distance
```

If I remove `ORDER BY` clause, it executes fine. Is there any way I can calculate distance and get places which are certain distance far from my provided `latitude & longitude`?

Comment: That error has to do with using the same cursor object to perform multiple queries. Show your code.

Comment: I am running this query inside phpmyadmin, no code involved.

Comment: Sounds like a phpMyAdmin bug.

Comment: [search phpmyadmin bugs](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+commands+out+of+sync)

Answer (score 0):

That is in a Stored Procedure, correct?  You failed to `DEALLOCATE PREPARE`.